# Linear Approximation.

Tags: derivatives

Use linear approximation to approximate the number $ln(1.02)$.

This is what I did and it is still wrong on my online homework.

$f(x) = ln(x)$

$f'(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}$

$y=\dfrac{1}{x}(x-1)$

$y=\dfrac{1}{1.02}(1.02-1)= 0.0196$

Comment: You can just give me the reasoning on what I did wrong and I will try to work it out. I dont want you to think I want the answer.
Just that I am better working backwards with the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use $$f(x) \approx f(a) + f^{\prime}(a) (x-a)$$

What you wrote down is $$f(x) \approx f(a) + f^{\prime}(\pmb{x})(x-a)$$

Comment: Oh I think I get it now! Thanks

Comment: If you do it correctly, you should simply get 0.02.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use $$\ln(x+h)\sim \ln(x)+(\ln)'(x)h$$

In our case this would be $$\ln(1+0.02)\sim \ln(1)+\frac{1}{1}(0.02)$$

using that $(\ln)'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.